# Mplayer launch threw PHP script

Tags: php

I tried almost everything, my PHP script looks like this:

```
<?php

    exec('mplayer -input file=/var/www/aac_np.pls -really-quiet -ao alsa -idle', $output);
    echo implode('<br />', $output);

?>
```

Mplayer is launching and closing itself.. Any ideas how to make it in some other way?

**Edit:**

I modified it as suggested but its still not working:

```
<?php
    exec('mplayer -slave -playlist /var/www/aac_np.pls &', $output);
    echo implode('<br />', $output);
?>
```

Comment: Seems it is being launched on foreground and closed by the php call termination. Try putting an ampersand & in the end of your command.

Comment: Would be 'mplayer -input file=/var/www/aac_np.pls -really-quiet -ao alsa -idle &'

Comment: Also make sure playlist path is correct and not empty.

Comment: I  modified it a littlebit because it was not even working on my terminal. But it is still not working, even after i added &.

It looks like this:
<?php
exec('mplayer -slave -playlist /var/www/aac_np.pls &', $output);
echo implode('<br />', $output);
?>

Comment: What is $output returning, can you var_dump() it?

Comment: Output: http://pastebin.com/LiMqF0bk

Comment: The end of file seems to talk about a connection problem with the streaming you want to use. Many possible reasons for that. Have you tried playing a local mp3/aac file first to see if it works, first?

Comment: I tried it now, it is no working too, here u have output:
http://pastebin.com/QfBAv5ZA

Comment: Please add the exec line you try for each output

Comment: Could you explain it ? Im newbie in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243327/how-to-run-mplayer-with-audio-speaker-output-from-php-web-script-on-linux):

The feature you are searching for works with the shell_exec() - function.

```
<?php 
shell_exec('sudo -u [username] nohup  mplayer -slave [mplayer attributes go here] 2> /dev/null > /dev/null &'));
?>
```

So your feature should work if you add your parameters to this function
and embed the function in your php script.

Comment: Agree, I skipped the function name. Still strange that he is getting an mplayer output instead of a php syntax error

Comment: This is how my script looks now:
http://pastebin.com/PEy2Jf0G
When i launch it by console php script.php it works but when i launch it in browser it doesnt.

Comment: maybe the path `/var/www/1.mp3` is interpreted different

Comment: How different? Is there any other way to set that path?